# How to avoid cartesian product in Oracle sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having performance issue with the following query in Oracle:

```
create table table2 as
select t.tab_key, t.x, t.y, t.val , s.val val2, sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) d
from table1 t
join table1 s on s.val is not null and 
                s.tab_key != t.tab_key and
                sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) <= 290;
```

I have to join table1 with the same table and select pairs having elements within a ceratin distance. So it's like cartesian product but significanty restricted by the condition `sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) <= 290`. The problem is that table1 has 700K rows and will become even larger in the future. That is why I want to avoid cartesian product.

What indexes should I use to speed up my query? Or should I change the query?

**Edit**:
I can't provide the data, but here's the explanation.
In table1, each row has a distinct key (tab_key), coordinates on a map (x and y), and value (val). Now, I would like to pair rows but only if the distance between them on a map is smaller than 290. So, it's like a cartesian product but significantly restricted by the condition `sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) <= 290`.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the query logic.

Comment: There is no way to avoid cartesian product because you have to evaluate every combination of rows. My only suggestion is to try something else like databricks that you can get stupid amounts of power to get through the calcs then turn it off when you're done.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Is there a way to impose the condtion `sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) <= 290` before the cartesian product happens? Or maybe I could create some partitions on the table depending on the coordinates?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid There is no way to avoid the Cartesian join but you can restrict the join from considering rows which are obviously going to be outside the circular radius you are filtering on so that the Cartesian join is only performed on a sub-set of the table rather than considering the entire table for every row.

Comment: As an alternative approach you can store the X,Y values as point geometry in an Oracle sdo_geometry column. Create a spatial index and use sdo_within_distance to get all points within a specified distance.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_within_distance.htm#SPATL1041

Comment: @Rene Oracle Spatial & Graph is a [cost option](https://www.oracle.com/assets/technology-price-list-070617.pdf) so you shouldn't use it unless you intend to pay for it.

Comment: @MTO. A lot of spatial functionality is part of Oracle Locator, a feature of Oracle standard edition. Here's the Oracle 11 documentation on what you can use under Locator without an extra license. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_locator.htm
Even more functionality in Oracle 12 Locator.

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid a cartesian product; however, you can provide additional restrictions so that obvious differences between co-ordinate values are filtered out before evaluating the exact distance between co-ordinates and performing the join.

You are trying to see if one co-ordinate is within a circle of radius 290 units from another co-ordinate. If the the value is within this circle then it is also within a bounding box surrounding the circle; this may allow you to use an index on the `x` and `y` co-ordinates.

You can also get rid of the (expensive) square root operation in the `JOIN` by squaring both sides; however, this may not be a significant saving as you'll still be performing the square root for the matched rows.

```sql
create table table2 as
select t.tab_key,
       t.x,
       t.y,
       t.val,
       s.val val2,
       sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) d
from   table1 t
       join table1 s
       on (   s.val is not null
          and s.tab_key != t.tab_key
          AND t.x BETWEEN s.x - 290 AND s.x + 290
          AND t.y BETWEEN s.y - 290 AND s.y + 290
          and power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2) <= power(290, 2)
          );
```

---

So:

```sql
CREATE INDEX table1__tk_v_x_y_idx ON table1( tab_key, val, x, y );
```

Then:

```sql
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select t.tab_key,
       t.x,
       t.y,
       t.val,
       s.val val2,
       sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) d
from   table1 t
       join table1 s
       on (   s.val is not null
          and s.tab_key != t.tab_key
          AND t.x BETWEEN s.x - 290 AND s.x + 290
          AND t.y BETWEEN s.y - 290 AND s.y + 290
          and power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2) <= power(290, 2)
          );

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

gives the output:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                           |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | Plan hash value: 2623360073                                                                 |
> |                                                                                             |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation          | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                      |     1 |   104 |     4  (50)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  MERGE JOIN        |                      |     1 |   104 |     4  (50)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   2 |   SORT JOIN        |                      |     5 |   260 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN | TABLE1__TK_V_X_Y_IDX |     5 |   260 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  4 |   FILTER           |                      |       |       |            |          | |
> | |*  5 |    SORT JOIN       |                      |     5 |   260 |     2  (50)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  6 |     INDEX FULL SCAN| TABLE1__TK_V_X_Y_IDX |     5 |   260 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                             |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                         |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                         |
> |                                                                                             |
> |    4 - filter("S"."TAB_KEY"<>"T"."TAB_KEY" AND "T"."X"<="S"."X"+290 AND                     |
> |               "T"."Y">="S"."Y"-290 AND "T"."Y"<="S"."Y"+290 AND                             |
> |               POWER("T"."X"-"S"."X",2)+POWER("T"."Y"-"S"."Y",2)<=84100)                     |
> |    5 - access(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("T"."X")>="S"."X"-290)                                      |
> |        filter(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("T"."X")>="S"."X"-290)                                      |
> |    6 - filter("S"."VAL" IS NOT NULL)                                                        |
> |                                                                                             |
> | Note                                                                                        |
> | -----                                                                                       |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                                     |
> ```

You get a very different explain plan from your query:

```sql
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select t.tab_key,
       t.x,
       t.y,
       t.val,
       s.val val2,
       sqrt(power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2)) d
from   table1 t
       join table1 s
       on (   s.val is not null
          and s.tab_key != t.tab_key
          and power(t.x - s.x, 2) + power(t.y - s.y, 2) <= power(290, 2)
          );

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

gives:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                              |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 806357607                                                                     |
> |                                                                                                |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation             | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |                      |     1 |   104 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS         |                      |     1 |   104 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN     | TABLE1__TK_V_X_Y_IDX |     5 |   260 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  3 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| TABLE1__TK_V_X_Y_IDX |     1 |    52 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                            |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                                            |
> |                                                                                                |
> |    3 - filter("S"."VAL" IS NOT NULL AND "S"."TAB_KEY"<>"T"."TAB_KEY" AND                       |
> |               POWER("T"."X"-"S"."X",2)+POWER("T"."Y"-"S"."Y",2)<=84100)                        |
> |                                                                                                |
> | Note                                                                                           |
> | -----                                                                                          |
> |    - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)                                        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e4929a0c56bacd961ae0e260f94d0b15)*

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. Why did you create an index on 4 columns tab_key, val, x, y instead of an index on two columns x, y or two indexes on x and y separately?

Comment: 4 columns allows you to just use the index; however, just an index on x any y can give you a benefit too - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48bb767accb0cb89b2a06c8b3d02fab7) shows it using an `INDEX RANGE SCAN` on the `x` and `y` columns to restrict the rows it needs to join.

Comment: Excellent observation about pre-filtering with a less intensive predicate.

Answer (score -1):

You can't add index which will improve your query because indexes are based on table and that one has to be based on two tables (the same but it can't be done that way).

Database has to start with one table and check every single row from second table if it meets your condition. I think it can't be done in other way. It is like asking a question: "Please find me every place close to every other place" - you have to check all of combinations.